# I can ping IPs but can't resolve domains

Tags: ubuntu, dns

I have Xubuntu 14.04 installed on my server. `network-manager` is not installed. It seems to have lost its ability to resolve domains, and I'm not sure where to begin diagnosing the issue.

`ping 8.8.8.8` pings normally.

`ping google.com` returns `ping: unknown host google.com`.

I tried adding a DNS server to `/etc/network/interfaces/`. Now it contains:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.100
gateway 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

This didn't fix the problem, so I tried running:

```
hesse@galois:~$ sudo service networking restart
stop: Job failed while stopping
start: Job is already running: networking
```

I tried `stop` then `start` and `reload` but they didn't seem to do anything.

How do I diagnose the problem?

Note: It is a lot of work for me to restart the machine (I need to connect a keyboard and monitor to it), so please suggest solutions that don't require restarting if possible.

---

**/etc/resolv.conf**:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` to your question?  That's the file that most resolvers will use to find which DNS servers to use

Comment: @EricRenouf Sure, it's empty except for the comment.

Comment: well that's the problem I suspect.  Not being able to restart `networking` is a problem, but are you sure you're not using `NetworkManager` instead?

Comment: Also, as a temporary solution you could just edit `resolv.conf` not withstanding that comment and add `nameserver 8.8.8.8`, but it will likely be overwritten at some point so that is just a temporary fix

Comment: @EricRenouf Typing `NetworkManager` brings up `The program 'NetworkManager' is currently not installed.`, so I'm guessing I'm not using it. The temporary solution works, what is the permanent fix?

Comment: Well, I think you'd have to figure out why you couldn't restart the network service, perhaps with clues in `/var/log/messages` or similar.  Your config looks right, so the next time the service restarts I suspect it will fill in the file right fro you

Comment: @EricRenouf https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/1301015

Answer (score 16):

You need to solve the emptiness of your /etc/resolv.conf before hoping for some other error.

It should reflect at least one resolver. Should this be the only problem, your resolving should work.

Try

```
vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

Go into the edit mode. Add the below thing:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

See post that if

```
ping google.com
```

Works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
```

Which will open a blank resolv.conf.d file in the nano text editor. You will need to place your DNS server address on the first line of this file and remember to end the line with a carriage return (hit enter) as seen below:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```